# Is there a way to shorten a java.security.MessageDigest generated value?

Tags: java, string, security, message-digest

If I generate a message digest (for a security feature in my app) using this Java code:

```
java.security.MessageDigest saltDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
saltDigest.update(UUID.randomUUID().toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
String digest = String.valueOf(Hex.encode(saltDigest.digest()));
```

I end up with a really long string like the following:

```
29bcf49cbd57bbc41e601b399a93218ef99c6e36bae3598b5a5a64ac66d9c254
```

Not the nicest thing to pass on a URL!

Is there a way to shorten this?

Comment: You could use Base64 instead of simple Hex encoding. That should save a few characters.

Comment: True, thanks. I forgot about looking at the other classes in that package: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/codec/package-summary.html I wonder how much Base64 would impact how "secure" the digest is. If it's really only a question of a few characters, I guess probably not that much.

Comment: since Base64 and Hex encoding represent the exact same information, the security of the content would be unaffected. *However* if some automated tool tries to handle your value, then it probably expects it to always be in the same format.

Comment: Ok, I see. Well this is just information that's being passed around in URLs and HTML form posts in a Spring MVC app. So there are no automated tools that rely on a particular format. It's just going to be used in database lookups in combination with a PK to ensure that only people with valid privileges can modify entities. Whether this is a good idea or not is another question. But I understand your point about how Hex & Base64 don't alter the underlying content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that's the expected size of a SHA-256 hash, right? You could always do

```
String sha256 = yourSha256Calculation();
sha256.substring(0,10);
```

To get a shorter string, but that would not be SHA-256. What are you really trying to achieve?

SHA-256 is not the shortest hash out there, look at http://www.fileformat.info/tool/hash.htm?text=hello for a comparison.

Comment: I see. Well, I'm trying to generate some unique value that can be associated with an entity (besides its primary key) to make it accessible only to those who have the digest value. My idea was that it would be extremely unlikely for someone to have both the digest value and the pk by chance - although they might have one or the other by chance.

Comment: What kind of output would you like? Is it the length of the string that is the problem? What about a smaller hash size, like MD5 or CRC? You can compare outputs here http://www.fileformat.info/tool/hash.htm?text=hello.

Comment: Dude! You rock. Awesome link. Exactly what I needed. Yeah, CRC might be fine. Thanks, man.

Comment: @arezzo: Note that not all those hashes are secure.

Comment: @Christoffer Hammarström: Thanks. You're right. I need to consider this. For security reasons I may not be able to afford a CRC32 hash since I am using the same calculation for my password hash.

Comment: I don't quite understand your setup, but are you making a hash of the PK, or do you simply want to make a separate, unique string? If the hash is generated from the PK, then your hash should indeed be as safe as possible. If you want a short yet powerful hash, consider making your own hash (e.g. taking the CRC of the SHA256 of your input with an added salt, or whathever you want). This function must  be unknown to the public.