# How to uniquely identify a Android Device in Android 10

Tags: android, uniqueidentifier

How can we uniquely indentify an Android Device in Android 10 as from Android 10 IMEI can not be fetched programmatically and as per our business policy one user can login into only one device (which we are identifying using IMEI upto android 9).

Settings.Secure#ANDROID_ID as suggested in many places is not reliable and can be reset upon factory reset and as per developer site InstanceID is not doing any good in my case.

Comment: Kindly refer this link https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58103580/android-10-imei-no-longer-available-on-api-29-looking-for-alternatives