# Unique identifier for identifying an android mobile in android 10

Tags: google-contacts-api

I am having a use case in which a user can log in from only a specific device. Prior to android 10
it was easy as the device identifier like IMEI,serial number was accessible. Each user ID'S were mapped against one IMEI(one to one mapping). 
But in android 10 these identifiers are not accessible. Hence unable to uniquely identify the device. 
How can we access the IMEI number in android 10 or any alternate identifier which can uniquely identify a device.

Comment: Please See this answer , Maybe help you . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67270143/unique-id-for-each-android-device/70459287#70459287

Answer (score 0):

Check first Answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58103580/android-10-imei-no-longer-available-on-api-29-looking-for-alternatives/59050182#59050182).

it's using UUID with MediaDrm.

**Tested** on Xiaomi Pocophone F1 with Android 10
and it survived **reboot, uninstall**.

I didn't test it yet over the factory reset.