# Unique ID for each android device

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am actually developing an android app looking to capture a unique Id for each android device but am not sure which Id is reliable

Telephony numbers **Imei/imsi** - Starting android 10, third-party apps will not be able to retrieve this id even though the permission is provided.

Secure ID - This id is sensitive to factory reset so it's not reliable.

Serial No: some phone has a serial number and some doesn't so not reliable

UUID- Generated by our app, which gets changed during the installation of every new release.

Is there any unique Id that doesn't have any dependency on the android version and doesn't change during factory reset as well?

Comment: Use your own key.

Comment: The key should vary with respect to each device and irrespective of number of times new release is installed in a device, the key should be the same.  That cannot be achieved via our own key. Aren't there any other unique Id for a device

Comment: then use a public API. store the data the from device and assign a unique id to the device. this should be done at app launch.

Comment: This would fail when we do a factory reset. :(

Comment: did you try this or making an assumption?

Comment: Yes it will definitely fail. Since we're doing a factory reset , all the user defined data will get resetted

Comment: this is serious then. may be you need to compromise somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method. I use it and take good result for many devices. You can added more than devices by calling adb shell getprop and read any unique value.

Reference : https://gist.github.com/flawyte/efd23dd520fc2320f94ba003b9aabfce

```
public static String getSerialNumber() {
    String serialNumber;

    try {
        Class<?> c = Class.forName("android.os.SystemProperties");
        Method get = c.getMethod("get", String.class);

        serialNumber = (String) get.invoke(c, "gsm.sn1");

        if (serialNumber.equals(""))
            serialNumber = (String) get.invoke(c, "ril.serialnumber");

        if (serialNumber.equals(""))
            serialNumber = (String) get.invoke(c, "ro.serialno");

        if (serialNumber.equals(""))
            serialNumber = (String) get.invoke(c, "sys.serialnumber");

        if (serialNumber.equals(""))
            serialNumber = (String) get.invoke(c, "ro.boot.serialno");

        if (serialNumber.equals(""))
            serialNumber = (String) get.invoke(c, "ro.ril.oem.sno");

        if(serialNumber.equals(""))
            serialNumber = (String) get.invoke(c, "ril.cdma.esn");

        if(serialNumber.equals(""))
            serialNumber = (String) get.invoke(c, "ro.boot.ap_serial");


        if(serialNumber.equals(""))
            serialNumber = (String) get.invoke(c, "ro.vendor.hon.imei.num");

        if(serialNumber.equals(""))
            serialNumber = (String) get.invoke(c,"ro.vendor.hon.extserial.num");

        if (serialNumber.equals("")){
            serialNumber= (String)get.invoke(c, "vendor.gsm.serial");
            serialNumber = serialNumber.substring(0,serialNumber.indexOf(' '));
        }
        if(serialNumber.equals(""))
            serialNumber = ((String)get.invoke(c,"ro.ril.oem.wifimac")).replace(":","");

        if (serialNumber.equals(""))
            serialNumber = ((String) get.invoke(c,"ro.ril.oem.btmac")).replace(":","");


        if (serialNumber.equals(""))
            serialNumber = Build.SERIAL;
        if (serialNumber.equals(Build.UNKNOWN))
            serialNumber = null;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        serialNumber = null;
    }

    return serialNumber;
}
```